# Bias of variance/precision estimator using Gamma prior

Tags: variance, prior, bias

Assume I have $N$ samples $x_1, \cdots, x_N$ from a Gaussian random variable $X\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ where both $\mu$ and $\lambda = 1/\sigma^2$ are unknown.

If I apply MLE, I have $\mu_{MLE} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i x_i$, and $\lambda_{MLE}^{-1} = \frac{1}{N} \sum_i (x_i - \mu_{MLE})^2$.
Note that $\lambda_{MLE}^{-1}$ is biased, and the unbiased estimate will be
$\frac{N}{N-1} \lambda_{MLE}^{-1}$.

Now, I have a Gamma distribution $Gamma(a_0, b_0)$ as a prior for $\lambda$.

With $N$ samples, we have that the posterior of $\lambda$ is $Gamma(a_N, b_N)$ where $a_N = a_0 + N/2$ and $b_N = b_0 + N/2 \lambda_{MLE}^{-1}$.

Obviously, if I choose $a_0=0$ and $b_0=0$, then I reach the MLE solution, which is biased.

My question is, is there any prior for $\lambda$ that gives me an unbiased estimate $\frac{N}{N-1} \lambda_{MLE}^{-1}$?
It seems that $a_0=-1/2, b_0=0$ does the job, but that does not define a proper Gamma distribution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a general result of [(Blackwell and Girshik, 1954)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1F2B-8ap4wwC&q=unbiased#v=snippet&q=unbiased&f=false): ***There is no (proper) prior distribution leading to the posterior expectation being an unbiased estimator***.

**proof** [(Blackwell and Girshik, 1954)](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1F2B-8ap4wwC&q=unbiased#v=snippet&q=unbiased&f=false): Assume that the posterior expectation (and Bayes estimate under the squared error loss)
$$
\delta(x) = \mathbb{E}[\theta|X=x]
$$
is unbiased for $\theta$, i.e. satisfies
$$
\mathbb{E}_{\theta_0}[\delta(X)]=\theta_0
$$
for every value of $\theta_0$ (where the expectation is under the conditional distribution of $X$ given $\theta=\theta_0$. Then, by Fubini's theorem, using the joint distribution of $(\theta,X)$,
$$ 
\mathbb{E}[\theta \delta(X)] =
\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[\theta|X]\delta(X)] = \mathbb{E}[\delta(X)^2]
$$
if we first integrate in $\theta$ and
$$
\mathbb{E}[\theta \delta(X)] =
\mathbb{E}[\theta\mathbb{E}[\delta(X)|\theta]] = \mathbb{E}[\theta^2].
$$
if we first integrate in $X$. Therefore, the Bayes risk is null,
$$
\mathbb{E}[\{\theta - \delta(X)\}^2] = 0,
$$
which is impossible (except in the uninteresting settings where the true value of the parameter can be known for sure). $\blacksquare$

---

Naturally, if we remove the condition that the prior is *proper*, there are many instances of the contrary: it is possible to derive unbiased estimators as posterior expectations with improper priors, as shown in the question for $a_0=-1/2$ and $b_0=0$.

Comment: In the last comment, do you mean $a_0=-1/2, b_0=0$? Because $a_0=0, b_0=0$ leads to a biased estimate for variance.